# How to dynamically define a value as a hyperlink Action in an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008 R2 in which two reports have been created under the same solution.  I need to know how to disable the hyperlink action for a column value that is equal to 0.

Of the two reports, one is the default main report and the other is a child that opens and displays records associated with a record from the main form.  This is triggered by a field called Diff.  Right now, all of the values under the Diff column display as a hyperlink, including those that are 0.  But there is no point in providing a hyperlink if the value is 0, as it will just open a child form that does not contain any records.  How do I disable the action of opening another report for where the Diff value = 0?

Using the following expressions in the Text Box Properties / Font tab, I was able to display the Diff value as Black vs Blue, Default vs Underline, and Default vs Bold based on a value of 0.  But I could not find an expression associated with Action.

```
=IIF(Fields!Diff.Value = 0, "Black", "Blue")
=IIF(Fields!Diff.Value = 0, "Default", "Underline")
=IIF(Fields!Diff.Value = 0, "Default", "Bold")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.  I ran searches but could not find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Text Box Properties of your Diff field, you should be able to set an expression for the Go To Report action:

[image: Go To Report Action properties with emphasized expression buttons]

Then just conditionally set the report in your expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Diff.Value = 0, Nothing, "ChildReport")
```